# Predicting the frequency of the individual, ranked words of a text

Tags: analysis, functions

In general, a power function like this, very well describes the relationship between word rank and word frequency: f(x) = predicted word frequency = constant * rank number^-1. (The constant varies from text to text and is a bigger number for a long text and a smaller number for a text with fewer unique words).

However, this typically does not hold for the 10-30 highest ranked words. Do you have a suggestion - apart from skipping the first occurrences as outliers? For your background: It seems that Zipf's Law does not cover the first part of the ranked vocabulary of a specific text.

[The image shows the relationship for a specific text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvMhM.png)

Comment: A suggestion for what? A curve that better fits a set of word-frequency statistics for a given language?

Comment: Yes, for at given text. I find that the power function, in general, is the best fit, however it is interesting that the fit can be very good, R2 > 0,97, and at the same time (invariably) the first words are poorly described by the function. A specific example of the function for a text with 3.420 words looks like this: f(x) = 5.141*rank^-1,076.